# Desired State Configuration for Web-Asp-Net452

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, powershell, dsc

I am trying to set up a WindowsFeature for .NET Framework 4.5.2 in DSC file but this version doesn't exist in the machine by default. How to install it on the machine remotely by defining configuration in the script? 
For ASP.Net 4.5 I have:

```
WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
{
    Name = "Web-Asp-Net45"
    Ensure = "Present"
}
```

Comment: 4.5.2 is the *framework* version, not the ASP.NET version. It's a binary replacement for earlier 4.0 and 4.5 versions. If you install the 4.5.2 version of the framework, it will replace any older 4.x versions and any 4.0+ web applications will use the new version.

Comment: But DSC doesn;t support this version. It works only up to 4.5. My machine doeasn't have 4.5.2 and I want to install it remotely.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't? You've only tried to install the ASP.NET feature. Anyway, 4.5.2 (or 4.6) aren't Windows Features, they are separate downloads. They may be bundled as features in Windows 2016. To upgrade to the .NET 4.5.2 *runtime* you need to use a different command. You can [download the offline installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx), create a DSC configuration that will copy it to each machine and then  execute it